# Omitting the cover pages in memoir

Tags: memoir

How do I omit the cover pages in a document of class `memoir`? i.e. the "Book X - My XXX book" pages in the example below.

Apologies if it is straightforward.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\book{My first book}
\begin{titlingpage} \end{titlingpage}
\lipsum[1-10]

\book{My second book}
\begin{titlingpage} \end{titlingpage}
\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
%\book{My first book}
%\begin{titlingpage} \end{titlingpage}
\lipsum[1-10]
%\book{My second book}
\newpage\setcounter{page}{1}
%\begin{titlingpage} \end{titlingpage}
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```

Or ...

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\def\book{\clearpage\setcounter{page}{1}}
\begin{document}
\book{My first book}
\lipsum[1-10]
\book{My second book}
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Ended up with `\renewcommand{\book}[1]{\cleardoublepage \setcounter{page}{1} }`.

Comment: Semi-apologies for being a GOM. Why are you using `\book` which, like `\part`, `\chapter` etc indicates a division in the text of the document? I tried you MWE with the redefinition you claimed for `\book` and got a bunch of text in the middle of which the page numbers reverted to 1. The vast majority of your potential readers would either not notice this or would be terribly confused by the change. What is it that you are trying to achieve?